# дергается персонаж когда фпс выше 60

Tags: unity3d

Столкнулся с проблемой персонаж начинается дергаться когда повышается фпс, даже если чуть повышается. Когда 60 то все хорошо идет ровно не чего не дергается.
Из за чего это может быть? и как это исправить?

2d игра

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))] 

public class HeroControl : MonoBehaviour {
Rigidbody2D rb2D;
// Animator anim;

private bool isGround = false;
public Transform groundCheck;
private float groundRadius = 0.4f; 
public LayerMask whatIsGround; 
public float maxSpeed = 4.5f;


void Start()
{
    rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    //  anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update()
{
    //GameObject someEnemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("enemy");              
    if (isGround && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) 
    {
        rb2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 900)); // прыжок
    }

    if (isGround && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) 
    {
        rb2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 900)); // прыжок
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{        

    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 0)
    {
        //  anim.SetInteger("Position", 0);
    }
    else
    {
        flip(); //flip

    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        // anim.SetInteger("Position", 2);
    }


    isGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround); 

    float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(move * maxSpeed * Time.deltaTime, rb2D.velocity.y);
    // rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(move * maxSpeed, rb2D.velocity.y);
    // rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 4f, rb2D.velocity.y);    

void flip()
{
    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0) transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0) transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) 
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "enemy")
        // SceneManager.LoadScene("lvl1");
        UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
}
}
```

Comment: 2d или 3d игра? Покажите метод, которым вы двигаете персонажа в пространстве

Comment: Полагаю, движение у вас относительно линейно? Т.е. персонаж двигается в основном продолжительное время линейно в одну сторону?

Comment: ну не совсем в одно (влево, вправо, и вверх)

Comment: попробуйте выставить интерполяцию или экстраполяцию в настройках rigidbody вашего героя. Это решит проблему?

Comment: сейчас получилось так что в момент прыжка дергается а если на право то все плавно

Answer (score 0):

При перемещении в FixedUpdate  попробуйте все умножать на Time.fixedDeltaTime

```
rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(move * maxSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, rb2D.velocity.y);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86287/discussion-on-answer-by-andrey------60).